# Independence number

Tags: graph-theory

I know the independence number of a graph is the largest subset of vertices in a simple graph such that no two vertices are adjacent.
I also understand the independence number of a Q3 graph is 4.
What about Q4 ? What about Qn in general ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to prove by induction that the independence number of $Q_n$ is $2^{n-1}$.

Hint: You form $Q_{n+1}$ from $Q_n$ by taking two copies of $Q_n$ and joining the corresponding vertices. Half of each set of vertices forms your independent set, by the induction hypothesis.